# Как получить название(идентификатор) почтового клиента, который установлен в браузере по умполчанию, при активации ссылки с mailto

Tags: javascript

Как с помощью javascript(jquery) получить название(идентификатор) почтового клиента, который установлен в браузере по умполчанию, при активации ссылки с mailto? Заранее благодарю за внимание!

Comment: если нужно на javascript, то боюсь, что никак.

Comment: IMHO никак. Это настройка не браузера, а общесистемная (в винде).

Comment: Не хватит доступа. Общедоступными средствами не получится, через ActiveX можно получить, но большинство браузеров отправит ваш код в бан как вредоносный. Пример читать реестр вот: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20421426/js-read-registry-values-in-javascript (эта информация хранится у Win в реестре)

Comment: а кроме винды есть ещё много осей...